# Creation of more than one bucket using Amazon S3 on CEPH cluster failes with Error Code 503

Tags: python, amazon-s3, storage, ceph

> Blockquote
>   I am new to ceph hand Amazon S3. I am trying to create more than one bucket with following python script, however I am getting below error.

```html
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
access_key = 'xxx'
secret_key = 'xxxxxxx=='

conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id = access_key,aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,host = '127.0.0.1',port = 8000,is_secure=False,               calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),)
bucket = conn.create_bucket('my-new-bucket')
bucket2 = conn.create_bucket('my-new-bucket2')
bucket3 = conn.create_bucket('my-new-bucket3')
```

Below is the error message:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonS3.py", line 8, in <module>
    bucket2 = conn.create_bucket('my-new-bucket2')
  File "/home/vivekanand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 619, in create_bucket
    data=data)
  File "/home/vivekanand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 671, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/home/vivekanand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/home/vivekanand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1028, in _mexe
    raise BotoServerError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 503 Slow Down
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>SlowDown</Code></Error>
```

One bucket gets created successfully. But creation of second bucket bucket fails with error code 503.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon is throttling your bucket create operations. Amazon does not want you to create one bucket after another in rapid succession. You are limited to the number of buckets that you can create (100). I don't know why Amazon throttles bucket create operations, maybe it is an expensive operation internally to setup storage.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I figured out the same. In my case the max allowed bucket creation request for this userid was 1 per hour. That is why I was getting this error.

Comment: It sounds like OP is using ceph emulating S3 not genuine S3, with boto as the client. For S3, bucket creation is indeed an expensive operation as you speculated, as all regions know of the existence and location of all buckets. [*"Because bucket operations work against a centralized, global resource space, it is not appropriate to create or delete buckets on the high-availability code path of your application. It is better to create or delete buckets in a separate initialization or setup routine that you run less often."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)